# How 404 page will work

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my error page i dont know exactly what is but i want to redirect this kind of error to 404.html page:

[image: Error]

1. I have created a 404 error page name "404.html". I want to redirect to this if no file or folder exist in my server.
2. Where do I have to place this page (404.html)?
3. Is it possible to redirect this page in .htaccess (or possible with only .htaccess)?
4. If is there anything more about 404 page let me know, I want to grab the knowledge.

And don't vote me down if possible of copy!

I want to map one error document file for 404 500 i am trying with this code.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
ErrorDocument 500 /404.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# map them to one error document:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/404/$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/500/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /404.html [L]
```

I tried this code and uploaded the file in main folder  `www.website.com/404.html`

Comment: Use the ErrorDocument directive, see: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html for documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No answer needed.
2. Where you want on your server
3. Yes : `ErrorDocument 404 /yourPath/404.html`
4. Google and Apache docs are your friends.

**Edit** : You add an image on your question. This is a `500 Internal Server Error`, and not a `404 Page not Found` error. Handle it with

```
ErrorDocument 500 /yourPath/500.html
```

But if your `.htaccess` file is corrupted and cause this error, you first have to fix your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Do i have to create a new 500.html for this..? @Al Fonce

Comment: i want to map same file for both errors 404 and 500 how can i do that

Comment: @ `ErrorDocument 500 /yourPath/404.html` will redirect all your 500 errors to your 404 page.

Comment: I think .htaccess issues are caused by trying to overwrite PHP settings, being uploaded in binary format or permissions issues.

Comment: @AbdulWaheed Try removing your `RewriteCond/RewriteRules` lines as it is not part of the initial question. Keep only the `ErrorDocument lines` and investigate. Don't edit too often your question.

Comment: okay..Tried as like u said But still unable to identify that image error is coming.. :(

Answer (score 3):

Its easier then I expected just gave full url:after reading documentation.and it worked.

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.website.com/404.html
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.website.com/404.html
```

Comment: We Should not give Full URL. Because when Deploy the code in some other project , you have to change manually the hard coded value, rather you can give the page with out URL as work in most of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the document for error handling inside .htaccess similar to one below

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.htm
```

This will override apache's default 404 page. The 404.htm will be inside your root folder.

https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/error-documents-for-beginners/